# Check if a checkbox is checked and then delete an element

Tags: jquery, forms

I've got a series of forms with different ids. Each one has a checkbox in there. What I am trying to do is delete one of the forms if the checkbox within it is checked.

```
<form id="placement-form">
</form>
<form id="placement-form1">
</form>
<form id="placement-form2">
</form>
```

I've written a short function in jQuery which should in theory delete the form if the checkbox is "checked" but I can't get it to work. jQuery is below:

```
$(function() {
    $('.deleteSelected').click(function() { //fire when the button is clicked
        $('#placement-form:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
            $('#placement-form').remove();                
        });
    });
});
```

It's probably a little muddled but I'm still getting to grips with jQuery with a combination of the documentation and a bit of Googling..!

EDIT: Though I have just realised this script will only ever search on one form (#placement-form) I'm working on it now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$(function() {
    $('.deleteSelected').click(function() { //fire when the button is clicked
        $('form input:checkbox').each(function() {
          var checkbox = $(this);  
          if(checkbox.is(':checked')) checkbox.parents('form').remove();        
        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** Easiest way

```
$('.deleteSelected').click(function(){
    $('form input:checked').parents('form').remove();
});
```

**EXAMPLE** : http://jsfiddle.net/XjkHW/

Comment: you are welcome buddy.. i have included one sorter method, check that out.. check example as well.

Comment: Ah cool - your second way is a lot simpler. Amazing how much you can do with such little code in jQuery, pure JavaScript would have made this much more difficult!

Answer (score 0):

$('#placement-form') will find only an element with that ID, not others.  You should write something like:

```
$('.deleteSelected').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('form').remove();
});
```

Comment: Yeah I just realised that (see EDIT in my post)